# How to do waiting elements in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i have playbook which creating vm's. Me need to waiting when will appear network. How to do it if element don't exist?

Part my playbook:

```
    - ovirt_nics_facts:
        vm: "{{ vm }}"
        auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
      register: nics_facts
      until: (ovirt_nics[0].reported_devices[0].ips[0].address is search("10.10.20.")) or
             (ovirt_nics[0].reported_devices[0].ips[0].address is search("192.168.250."))
      retries: 20
      delay: 60
```

Error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ovirt_nics[0].reported_devices[0].ips[0].address is defined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ovirt_nics[0].reported_devices[0].ips[0].address is defined): list object has no element 0"}
```

Comment: When ansible run a task and register its output, it will not change that value if you dont run the task again. As it is static and you wait on another task for the results, it will always fail. You should run your task which register "ovirt_nics" until it shows up the ip address, then you can run the next task you need.

Comment: @KelsonSilva, i know, but i don't understand how to do it. You may show example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided trouble:

```
- name: add vm to temporary inventory
  block:
    - ovirt_nics_facts:
        vm: "{{ vm }}"
        auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
      register: nics_facts
      until: ovirt_nics[0].reported_devices|length > 0
      retries: 20
      delay: 60
```